# Objective -c/JSON: How to get ObjectForKey when it's a top level object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

my JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    post_number: "1",
    date: "2013-09-02",
    thumbnail: "thumbnail_address"
  },
  {
    post_number: "2",
    date: "2013-09-02",
    thumbnail: "thumbnail_address"
  },
  {
    post_number: "2",
    date: "2013-09-02",
    thumbnail: "thumbnail_address"
  },
]
```

I usually do something like this `NSArray *blogPostsArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];` but there's not a top level object called "posts". How do I get an array when there's no top level object in Objective -c?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: in your dic not key has name "posts" then how can you get its value??

Comment: @iPatel Yes. That's my point...

Comment: Where does `dataDictionary` come from? and how are you reading the JSON?

Comment: what exactly you want to fetch from above array ?

Comment: @Xman post number, date, and thumbnail

Comment: @Sebastian `NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];`

Comment: **but there's not top level object called "posts". How do I get an array when there's no top level object** Can You elaborate it?

Comment: you can easily get it as follows : [yourArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForeKey:@"post_number"]   similarly do for other keys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your top level object is an array instead of a dictionary, `NSJSONSerialization` will create an `NSArray` instance instead of a `NSDictionary`.
Therefore you can retrieve the contained objects via `objectAtIndex:` (or via `[]` in modern Objective-C):

```
NSArray* jsonArray = @[@{
                           @"post_number": @"1",
                           @"date": @"2013-09-02",
                           @"thumbnail": @"thumbnail_address"
                      },
                      @{
                           @"post_number": @"2",
                           @"date": @"2013-09-02",
                           @"thumbnail": @"thumbnail_address"
                      },
                      @{
                           @"post_number": @"2",
                           @"date": @"2013-09-02",
                           @"thumbnail": @"thumbnail_address"
                        }];
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonArray options:0 error:nil];
NSArray* deserializedArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary* first = deserializedArray[0];
NSLog(@"%@", first);
```